# Is there a way to convert SqlCommand to DbCommand?

Tags: database, enterprise-library

We have a SQL helper library that is over 13 years old, and it is used through out all applications. I would like to update it to use Enterprise Library DAAB. One road block for doing so is the difficulty of converting SqlCommand (used by the library and all applications) to DbCommand. Even though SqlCommand is inherited from DbCommand, I am having difficulty to explicitly convert SqlCommand to DBCommand - DAAB uses.   I don't want to change tens of thousands lines of code to break the SQL helper library interface in order to use the EL DAAB.

Would appreciate  pointers on this!

Answer (score -1):

I guess if the `DbCommand` in EL DAAB is a`System.Data.Common.DbCommand`, then you can just direct cast?

```
public void Main()
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = _connection.CreateCommand();
    // Now set up the SqlCommand properties...

    DbCommand baseCommand = (DbCommand) sqlCommand;
    var reader = baseCommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I tried direct cast before seeking for help here.